# Makefile needs to run definition twice, once to add to counter, the second to compile

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following makefile:

```
aCpp:=$(call rwildcard,$(srcDir),*.cpp)
aObjs=$(aCpp:.cpp=$(objEnd))
aObj=$(aObjs:$(srcDir)%=$(objDir)%)

totalCpp=$(words $(aCpp))
processed=    
$(objDir)%$(objEnd): $(srcDir)%.cpp
    $(CC) -MM -MP -MT $(df)$(objEnd) -MT $(df).d $(CFLAGS) $< > $(df).d
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
    $(eval processed+= x)
    @echo "$(words $(processed)) out of $(totalCpp) compiled."

default: $(aObj)
```

What I need to happen is to make the makefile test and see if the file needs to be compiled, then if it does add a counter to a variable, but not compile, once all of that is done, I then need it to go through and do the compiling piece again. More or less I need the `$(objDir)%$(objEnd): $(srcDir)%.cpp` definition to run twice, but with two different definitions.

The whole reason why I want to do this is to have a more accurate way of measuring how many files actually need to compile instead of having `5 out of 14 files processed. All done!` I want it to be modular and say `3 out of 3` or on the next one `7 out of 8` instead of the total files.

Would I have to run the counting in one makefile, put the result in a file, and run the second makefile?

Comment: Does having the target that lists those files as prereqs eval a make variable based on `$(words $?)` help here? (I don't know if that evaluates in the correct order or not offhand.)

Comment: misunderstood that, it does but only for the total amount of files to process, and not the total to actually compile.

Comment: Hm? `$?` is the number of prerequisites newer than the target. That should be only the object files that match the source files that have changed. Is that not the number you wanted?

Comment: Yes but no, I need the number or prerequisites newer than the target for the executable, before compiling running the definition of the prerequisites. <- this is what I meant.

Comment: And `eval` in the body of the executable target doesn't run early enough for that? What about trying it as a target-specific variable (which might need secondary expansion to work)?

Comment: It wasn't because it had to resolve it's dependencies first.

Comment: Oh well, it was a long shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, and here is the result:

```
CC=g++

objDir=obj/

srcDir=src

df=$(objDir)$(*F)

rwildcard=$(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))

aCpp:=$(call rwildcard,$(srcDir),*.cpp)
aObjs=$(aCpp:.cpp=$(objEnd))
aObj=$(aObjs:$(srcDir)%=$(objDir)%)

processed=
ifdef first
else
totalCpp:=$(shell make first=a)
endif
totalCppFake=

AUTODEPS:= $(patsubst $(srcDir)%.cpp,$(objDir)%.d,$(aCpp))

-include $(AUTODEPS)

$(objDir)%$(objEnd): $(srcDir)%.cpp
ifdef first
    $(eval totalCppFake+= x)
else
    @$(CC) -MM -MP -MT $(df)$(objEnd) -MT $(df).d $(CFLAGS) $< > $(df).d
    @$(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
    $(eval processed+= x)
    @echo "$(words $(processed)) out of $(words $(totalCpp)) compiled."
endif

default: $(exe)
ifdef first
else
    @echo "Done!"
endif

$(exe): $(aObj)
ifdef first
else
    @$(CC) $(aObj) -o $(exe) $(CFLAGS)
    @echo "Binary created!"
endif
```

Pretty much all I did was call a shell command that runs the make file again, and have a counter if the variable first exists, then get the length of that. It just hit me that I could just do this, with ifdef's to keep recursion (forever anyway) from constantly happening, and to allow it to work without compiling before I want to compile, which was my main concern.

I hope that my learning expierence can also help anyone who is wanting to do the same thing. And thanks to Etan Reisner for trying to help out, even though $? was not the thing I was looking for.

Comment: You are losing a lot of capability here.  This won't pass through any command line options or variable settings, it won't allow you to specify specific targets to be built, etc.  Personally I don't think this feature is worth the performance impact of running make twice, but if you really want it another option is to run `make -n` and count the number of rules invoked (in a script), then use that as the total.  For example `totalCpp := $(shell $(MAKE) -n $(MAKECMDGOALS) | grep <something> | wc -l)` or whatever.

Comment: To run the shell command `make first=a` it only takes 0.02 seconds. To do the command you are suggesting, it takes 0.19 seconds which is almost a tenth of the speed..

Comment: This sort of trick, but using make restarts, might work better. The exact details of how to make that work might be a little complicated though.

Comment: Anyway, you should accept your own answer here if your solution has been found.